# ASP.NET MVC 4 - Set input value using @Html.EditorFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Currently i have this field on a form:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AmountDecimal, 
  new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

But:

a) i want it to have the value "100" predefined

b) don't want it to be editable

I know how to do it in raw HTML but i need it to be in razor.

Thanks

Comment: The value will be taken from the `Model`'s `AmountDecimal`, you can change it there. The `disabled` attribute you can add to the same anonymous object that already contains the `class`.

Answer (score 3):

It would make sense to set this value e.g. in the constructor of your model or in the controller before you call your view

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        AmountDecimal= 100
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

But if you really like to do it in razor, you may use HiddenFor

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AmountDecimal, new { @Value = "100" });
<input type="text" name = "dummy" class="form-control" value="100" readonly/>
```

Keep in mind to never trust a user input ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think your are loooking for something like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AmountDecimal, 
  new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = "100", @readonly = "readonly"} })
```